# Set flag value to "0" if category ID is in_array (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, categories, adsense

I'm trying to set the `$ad_flg` value to "0" if category 549 is in the `$adsense_block_post`

```
<?php Global $ad_flg; $ad_flg=1; ?>
<?php $adsense_blck_category = array(549); ?> 
<?php if (array_key_exists  ($_category_id->ID,$adsense_blck_category,true)) $ad_flg=0; ?>`
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for array **keys**, not values. Use [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) instead:

```
<?php 

$adsense_blck_category = array(549);
$ad_flg = ! ( in_array($_category_id->ID, $adsense_blck_category) );

?>
```

As you'll see, your code may also be massively simplified by simply assigning the opposite return value of `in_array()` to your flag (using the `!` operator).

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/588230)

Comment: Yes but how do I check that value in an if statement?

Comment: Instead of assigning it to a variable, just wrap it in an `if()` block:

`if( ! ( in_array($_category_id->ID, $adsense_blck_category) ) )`